# Can't solve this integral $ \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \sin(x^{13})dx$

Tags: integration

Hi I don't know how to solve this integral. Wolfram alpha says its equal to $0$ and it's the answer to my college exam but I don't know how to solve it. Anyone mind taking a guess?

$ \int_{- \pi}^{\pi}\sin(x^{13})dx $

Thanks

Comment: Something odd about this question. That is a hint.

Comment: This is an odd function in a symetric range so the result should be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\,dx=\int_{-a}^0 f(x)\,dx+\int_0^a f(x)\,dx=\int_0^a f(-x)\,dx+\int_0^a f(x)\,dx.$$